# How to merge row if the occurrence of value more than one time

Tags: php

How to merge the row with same bookName if occurence is more that one time with addition of values booksgiven field.

````
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{ 
?>          

<tr>

<td><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($result->BookName);?></td>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($result->booksgiven);?></td>

</tr>

<?php $cnt = $cnt + 1;  }  } ?>  ```

How to merge the row with same bookName if occurence is more that one time with addition of values booksgiven field.
````

Comment: What you want, is called a _control break_. Basic principle is that you compare the bookname of the current record, with that of the previous one (your data needs to be sorted by bookname) - and based on whether they are different or the same, you decide what to do. Since you want to sum up a value over all records with the same bookname, you will need to hold back with creating the output table row for the current “group”, until that change to the next group occurs.

Comment: The other alternative would be handling most of this on the database side already - keywords GROUP BY and aggregate functions.

Comment: Mysql Select query is fetching data from different table. So how can I do this?     `  "SELECT tblbooks.BookName, 
       tblissuedbookdetails.booksgiven, 
       tblissuedbookdetails.id as rid join tblstudents on tblstudents.StudentId = tblissuedbookdetails.StudentId 
       join tblbooks on tblbooks.id = tblissuedbookdetails.BookId 
       where tblstudents.StudentId=:sid 
       order by tblissuedbookdetails.id desc"  `

Comment: Thanks group by method worked properly